# Query with OData URL

Tags: json, url, odata

I want write a query as URL to order by a column in OData URL descending format.

My data has a '_id' column in JSON format.

I tried the URL in below but it does not work. It showed me just first row in JSON format but I want to see the biggest id in JSON format.

```
https://HOSTNAME/en/datastore/odata3.0/7aec630d-2757-4da0-97f1-71b140abd818?$orderby=MAX(_id)&$format=json&$top=1
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of ODATA Backend implementations are not as sturdy as you might think:

There are two things I know of, that could result in above behaviour:

**Thing1**

Some implementations push some of the query options down to the database/business Layer, while letting others be handled by the generic ODATA resolver.

This effect you have can happen, for instance, when the TOP is handled by the backend implementation and pushed down to the database, without also pushing the order down to the database.

The Odata Resolving Framework then would perform the other operations (orderby) only on the remaining dataset (1 row).

To check if that is the case:

- leave out TOP and see if it works then (but gives you all entries).
- leave out the orderby and see if the first entry is the one you get when you do above query.

**Thing 2**

also, some backends cant do expressions, so MAX(...) would just be ignored

If it is the case, you have only the following option:

- Thing1: correct the backend implementation, which must make sure that pagination (TOP, skip) isnt handled before orderby.
- Thing2: implement expressions in the backend
- or handle it in the frontend

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation looks like an OData v3 compliant API.

> **[10.2.3.3 The $orderby System Query Option](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/odata-version-3-0-core-protocol/?#theorderbysystemqueryoption)**
> The `$orderby` System Query option specifies the order in which entities are returned from the service.
>
> The value of the `$orderby` System Query option contains a comma separated list of property navigation paths to sort by, where each property navigation path terminates on a primitive property.
>
> A type cast using the qualified entity type name is required to order by a property defined on a derived type.
>
> The property name MAY include the suffix “asc” for ascending or “desc” for descending, separated from the property name by one or more spaces. If “asc” or “desc” is not specified, the service MUST order by the specified property in ascending order.

Therefore, to order by `_id` in descending order, you should use this segment:

`$orderby=_id desc`

In which case the URL would be similar to:

```
https://HOSTNAME/en/datastore/odata3.0/7aec630d-2757-4da0-97f1-71b140abd818?$orderby=_id desc&$format=json&$top=1
```

Using the `Max()` function is not a known OData convention for ordering. If `Max()` was going to do anything it would evalutate to the same value for *all* records, the max value in the table, and would therefore not afect the ordering at all.